# Keep section visible as long as it is hovered

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've made a slidedown function based on `data` i put in links to execute on section `data`. The whole script works fine except the part where I need to access the section area. As long as I hover the link the section appears, but when I try to reach some ocntent in that section it dissapears, how do I do to make it up as long as my mouse is hovering the section content without haveing to change the html structure? And how do I keep that link underlined as well as long as the section is hovered?

HTML

```
<ul class="main-navbar-right">
    <li><a href="#" data-navigation="home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-navigation="explore">Explore</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-navigation="news">News</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="navigation-content">
    <section id="-navbar-home" data-section="home">
        <p>Home, some content images, videos and more and <a href="#">Link</a></p>
    </section>

    <section id="-navbar-explore" data-section="explore">
        <p>Home explore <a href="#">Link</a></p>
    </section>

    <section id="-navbar-explore" data-section="news">
        <p>Home news <a href="#">Link</a></p>
    </section>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#-navbar-home,
#-navbar-explore,
#-navbar-news {
    display: none;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

ul {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}

li {
    float: left;
    margin: 0 15px 0 0;
}

.active, a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

JavaScript

```
var elem;
$('li > a').hover(function() {
        var navigation = $(this).data("navigation");
        var section = $("section[data-section="+navigation+"]");
        elem = $(section).slideDown();
    }, function() {
        elem.hide()
});
```

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/66qz2by8/6/

Answer (score 2):

I think this would work for you. The .hide should only happen when leaving the larger div I added.

```js
$('.myapp').hover(function() {}, function() {
  $('section[data-section]').hide();
});

$('.main-navbar-right li > a').hover(
  function() {
    $('section[data-section]').hide();
    $("section[data-section=" + $(this).data("navigation") + "]")
      .slideDown();
  }, function(e) {}
);
```

```css
#-navbar-home,
#-navbar-explore,
#-navbar-news {
    display: none;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

ul {
  height: 20px;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
  margin: 0px;
}
.navigation-content {
  height: 50px;
}
li {
  float: left;
  margin: 0 15px 0 0;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.active, a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="myapp">
<ul class="main-navbar-right">
    <li><a href="#" data-navigation="home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-navigation="explore">Explore</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-navigation="news">News</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="navigation-content">
    <section id="-navbar-home" data-section="home" data-expanded="0">
        <p>Home, some content images, videos and more and <a href="#">Link</a></p>
    </section>

    <section id="-navbar-explore" data-section="explore" data-expanded="0">
        <p>Home explore <a href="#">Link</a></p>
    </section>

    <section id="-navbar-explore" data-section="news" data-expanded="0">
        <p>Home news <a href="#">Link</a></p>
    </section>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Very nice. Problem though when you move over to the next link: The old one stays.
Added some lines from my misguided answer to address this issue: https://jsfiddle.net/svArtist/62d86hao/

Comment: yes, nice catch. Feel free to edit the post above too if you are able.

Comment: I have only 373 rep, I could only suggest an edit. Can't you work it in? (I forked your fiddle and only added this fix plus a positioning fix (so they wouldn't move each other down when rolled out)

Comment: @BenPhilipp Thanks, it works fine except the part where the rest of my website dissapears..

Comment: Look at the jQuery where we hide all the sections. I assumed that all of the sections should be hidden, since there were no further sections in your fiddle.
I changed the code slightly, now only the sections inside your `navigation-content` container will disappear: https://jsfiddle.net/svArtist/62d86hao/1/

Comment: @Ben Philipp, I added some code handling to to fix the issue of overlapping content and added more specific selectors.

Answer (score 1):

instead of `.hover`, use `.mouseenter`.
Hide the last shown section before showing the new one.

see here: https://jsfiddle.net/svArtist/vttjbbLy/

var elem;

```
$('li > a').mouseenter(function () {
    var navigation = $(this).data("navigation");
    var section = $("section[data-section=" + navigation + "]");
    $("section").each(function () {
        if ($(this).data("section") != navigation) {
            $(this).fadeOut();
        }
    });
    elem = $(section).slideDown();
});
```

Comment: I see now that I have misunderstood the question a bit.
This might benefit other people still, so I will leave it in

Comment: Hi! I love this solution, however it does not work as good as expected. The thing is that when I hover on button the rest of the page magicly dissapears, and it doesn't hide when I get my mouse outside the menu...

Comment: Yes, as I said, I misunderstood the question a bit - I thought you wanted to display a section whenever the corresponding link was hovered, and have it stay visible until another section was chosen...

Answer (score 0):

There is a really simple way to do something similar to this using only CSS. What you could do is enclose the "dropping-down" element in the `li` itself, setting its height to 0px, then changing its height on hover, with a little bit of a trick (using overflow:hidden to hide the contents, and position:absolute to prevent the element from displacing the links):

Here's [the fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/ghipkins26/gguk2zpt/3/)

```
.dropdown {
    width:200px;
    max-height:0px;
    transition:all 0s ease;
    -moz-transition:all 0s ease;
    -ms-transition:all 0s ease;
    -o-transition:all 0s ease;
    -webkit-transition:all 0s ease;
    overflow:hidden;
    position:absolute;
}
li:hover .dropdown, .dropdown:hover {
    max-height:200px;
    transition:all .4s ease;
    -moz-transition:all .4s ease;
    -ms-transition:all .4s ease;
    -o-transition:all .4s ease;
    -webkit-transition:all .4s ease;
}
```